# set variable value in hive from select statement

Tags: hive

I have a subquery as below

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC WHERE DT BETWEEN (SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT) AND (SELECT MAX(DT) FROM FCT_DT)

Hive do not allow select in between clause,

can i capture select state in variable and pass to between clause

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, please explain in details. `(SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT)` - this returns all rows dates, not a scalar. and second subquery returns single date: `(SELECT MAX(DT) FROM FCT_DT)`. Should first subquery be somehow correlated with ABC table or is it a bug in it? And NO, you can not "select state in variable and pass to between clause" - in the same script it is impossible in Hive. Hive does not calculate variables, variables are just text substitution.

Comment: But it seems you can do it without variables, using subqueries/join. between can accept scalar values, not like select dt from FCT_DT. Select max() - is okay, it is scalar value and can be calculated in a subquery, joined and used in BETWEEN, first subquery - can not be used in BETWEEN

Comment: SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT , this will return just 1 rows, Hive is now supporting select statement in between clause i wanted to store the result of select in variable and use it in between clause. eg select count(*) from abc where dt between var and var  -> var = (SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT)

Comment: If SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT , this will return just 1 rows.... then whey do you need to aggregate the same in second suibquery (SELECT MAX(DT) FROM FCT_DT) --if it is one row in FCT_DT then aggregation makes no sence, between also makes no sense. Did you miss aggregation in the first subquery?

Comment: should it be `SELECT min(DT) FROM FCT_DT` instead of `SELECT DT FROM FCT_DT `??

Answer (score 0):

Create you table;

```
CREATE TABLE ABC ( send_org string,rec_org string, participants int );
insert into ABC values ( "b", "z", 1);
insert into ABC values ( "b", "z", 2);
insert into ABC values ( "b", "z", 3);
insert into ABC values ( "b", "z", 4);
```

Use `with` to help create "tables" that you can then reference in your query.

```
with 
   theMax as (SELECT max(participants) as max_ FROM ABC), 
   theMin as (select min(participants) as min_ FROM ABC)  
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) FROM ABC, theMax, theMin  
WHERE 
   participants between  theMin.min_ and theMax.max_
```

Comment: Really Nice thought